# cancan & rolify with multitenant architecture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, rolify

In multi tenant architecture, I can implement permission for admin of an organization using cancan like below:

```
def admin
  can :manage, ModelName, organization: { id: @user.organization_id }
end

def superadmin
  can :manage, :all
end
```

However, I don't know how to do something similar using rolify?

```
if user.has_role? :superadmin
  can :manage, :all
else
  if user.has_role? :admin
    ***can :manage, ModelName, :id => _______________ ***
  end
end
```

Apparently, I want admin can manage ModelName with all ids that belong to him, but how to get it through the User and organization?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using just rolify will be enough since rolify is just for managing user roles. What you need is an authorization system like [pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit).

I've been using rolify together with pundit and it's been working great for multitenant stuff.